# How to add blogger's RSS feed to facebook profile/page

Tags: facebook, rss

I have a blog and I want that whatever is posted in the blog should get directly posted on my facebook profile/page. Basically I wish to post my blog's RSS feed to my facebook profile/page. I used RSS Graffiti to accomplish the task but somehow it seems like that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You should forget about the user profile for that. First of all, you are not allowed to use the user profile for commercial reasons, it´s ONLY a user profile, for you and your friends, not a platform to advertise. And then there´s the problem with the Access Token. An Extended User Token lasts for 60 days, so you would have to refresh it every 2 months if you want to autopost stuff to Facebook.

Now for your Facebook Page, you can create an Extended Page Token that lasts forever. The rest is explained in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed#publish

In general, you need to use a Page Token with `publish_actions` to post to the `/page-id/feed` endpoint.

Information about Access Tokens and how to generate and extend them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

At this point, Facebook does not let you add an RSS feed to automatically do that. 
I would recommend using a tool like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) which does it very well!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook between 2009-2011 had a feature which allowed you to add blog feeds from any format to your profile so it would publish. It was later introduced into Facebook Pages and some how discontinued in the main profiles of users on Facebook, so that businesses appear as businesses and everyone else appears as everyone else, since currently on my profile on Facebook, my content from Flickr, Twitter, Google+, YouTube and my other accounts are automatically published to my main Facebook profile. This is because I signed up and started using Facebook in 2009 to the current date.

What really annoys me is that there is so much info online about how to do this but I have to say is that Facebook can easily adjust it's service to include RSS Feeds in it's platform through the app http:// facebook .com/apps/feed , which basically shows your updates from the games you play on Facebook, which is annoying that Facebook hasn't even got round to replacing RSS Feeds into profiles.

I'll send some support requests to Facebook (lets say tons of support requests) and I'll ask them to add it back in because other users are slightly annoyed. I'm annoyed with the childish icons that they have (including the icon for the Instagram app, which, yes, is owned by Facebook).

Another way is by connecting your apps that you use to your Facebook account by going to either the respective app in Facebook itself or by finding the setting Connect To Facebook in the Settings of your accounts on other Third-Party services. As an example, you can use PlayStation Network (PSN) by connecting your PlayStation account to your Facebook through the PS4 itself by going into Settings > Account Settings > Link Services > Facebook and then type in your login details, as usual. This will log you and keep you signed into your Facebook account on your PSN account. This means that everytime you interact with PSN by the associated Facebook service, your interaction is posted to Facebook based on the settings whether it's set to post as Private or Public. This means that everytime you play a game or decide to setup a Live Stream, your post is posted to Facebook from the PS4 automatically. Same method could also work with Blogger app for Facebook by connecting your Facebook to your Blogger account (in Google+ settings if you've switched to the new profile interface). So it's possible, yes, in other apps now more than before so it's also the reason for why Facebook probably removed Feeds.

If anyone wants to see my updates from my connected apps and connected data, you can follow my Public hashtag posts at http://facebook.com/search/top/?q=%23warrenwoodhouse and you can follow the same hashtag on every service available including PSN, Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Google Search, Google Images, Google Videos, YouTube, YouTube Gaming, Instagram, Flickr and other services. If you're interested in seeing my full feed updates, I've created a nice feed on FeedBurner at http:// feeds. feedburner .com/warrenwoodhouse